# Printing a href with php row error

Tags: php, html, css, row

Hi there i have a little problem regarding my php code.

I can't make it our of this error pictured in the images below.

I want to make .$row[title] clickable,so it that can open a new php page ,which i want to add some descriptions and the id from the link to be different.

the main problem:

```
 "<p><a href=\"desk.php?id=.$row["id"]\">.'<b>'.$row["titlu"].'</b>'. </a></p>".
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you post the code as text?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a typo. Change this:

```
 "<p><a href=\"desk.php?id=.$row["id"]\">.'<b>'.$row["titlu"].'</b>'. </a></p>".
```

To:

```
 "<p><a href=\"desk.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><b>".$row['titlu']."</b></a></p>".
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"<p><a href=\"desk.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><b>".$row['titlu']."</b></a></p>".
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the problem.

You can't use double quotes between double quotes

```
"<p><a href=\"desk.php?id=.$row['id']\">.'<b>'.$row['titlu'].'</b>'. </a></p>".
```